# error in view layer when trying to call method in bean in java 1.6

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I'm learning JSF/PRIMEFACES development, but when I try to create a bean with index.html I'm getting an error message.

I've already built the project, already configured my xml, and now I don't know what it might be.

Can someone help me ?

grateful

**Bean.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name=Bean)
public class Bean {
    private String word;
 
    private String anagram;
 
    public void generateAnagram() {
        Random rand = new Random();
 
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            characters.add(c);
        }
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(word.length());
        while (characters.size() != 0) {
            int randPicker = (int) (Math.random() * characters.size());
            output.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
        }
        this.anagram = output.toString();
    }
 
    public String getAnagram() {
        return anagram;
    }
 
    public void setAnagram(String anagram) {
        this.anagram = anagram;
    }
 
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
 
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="jsfexample">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">Anagram maker</f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel for="Word" value="Word" />
            <p:inputText id="Word" value="#{bean.word}" label="Word" />
            <h:outputLabel for="Anagram" value="Anagram" />
            <h:outputText id="Anagram" value="#{bean.anagram}" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton action="#{bean.generateAnagram}" update="Anagram"
                    value="Generate anagram" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**ERRO**

*2021-11-08 17:23:54,456 ERROR common.utils.DefaultExceptionHandlerOverride  ----> Unexpected error caught in view control layer.
javax.faces.FacesException: /pages/ws/index.xhtml @12,78 value="#{bean.word}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'Bean' resolved to null*

Comment: You have already verified the settings in bean.xml

Comment: Yes, if you want I can post.